# JavaScript: How can I make the CSS translate function end up in a given div regardless of where it starts?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to create a card game but I am stuck at the end point of the Translate function, the player has 30 cards (for programming I only use four since it is easier with less lines), when clicking on a card, the card makes an animation with translate and rotate to reveal the value of the card, and since I only need to reveal the value of 3 cards, I need them to end up in a specific place and be clearly visible, even if the user chooses consecutive cards.

The problem is that I can't make the card end in the div that has the Card1 label, since translate moves me according to the starting point and doesn't to the end point. Can someone help me find a way to do this with translate or is there any other way to do it?
Thank you!

```js
const card = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
const card2 = document.querySelector('.card2');
let fragment = document.querySelector(".solve");

card.forEach((card) => {
      card.style.display = 'block';
      card.onmousedown = function() {
        card.classList.add('animate');
      };
 });
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #100e17;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 280px;
  width: 1200px;
  top: 60px;
  left: calc(28% - 300px);
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  transform: perspective(600px);
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.card1 {
  display: flex;
  height: 260px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #17141d;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: -1rem 0 3rem #000;
}

.card2 {
  display: flex;
  height: 260px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: -1rem 0 3rem #000;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.animate {
  position: relative;
  transform: perspective(600px) translate(0px, 300px) rotateY(-180deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 3s;
}

.card .card1,
.animate .card .card2 {
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card .card2 {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.title {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 15px;
}

.answer {
  position: absolute;
  height: 260px;
  width: 300px;
  top: 360px;
  left: 250px;
  display: flex;
}

label {
  color: white;
}

.solve {
  display: flex;
  height: 260px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #17141d;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: -1rem 0 3rem #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card1">
      <h3 class="title">Card front 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card2">
      <h3 class="title">Card back 1</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card1">
      <h3 class="title">Card front 2</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card2">
      <h3 class="title">Card back 2</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card1">
      <h3 class="title">Card front 3</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card2">
      <h3 class="title">Card back 3</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card1">
      <h3 class="title">Card front 4</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card2">
      <h3 class="title">Card back 4</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="answer">
  <label for="solve">Card 1</label>
  <div class="solve" id="solve"></div>
</div>
```

[image: This is an example of what I am trying to do, I need three of the cards above to end in the 3 End Points]

Comment: One option I tried is: `card.style.setProperty('transform', 'translate(${fragment})'); ` but this doesn't let me add transition effects. And the other way I found was to create a function for each card with the transformations and transitions and then use switch. If anyone knows a better way it would be very helpful! Thank you!

Comment: There's a syntax error in your JavaScript: `SyntaxError: missing } after function body`; effectively you need to also close the call to `forEach()`, by adding `})` after you close the `onmousedown` function. Also, can you show (in a detailed picture, perhaps) where you want the cards to end? I think you want them to transition to an evenly-spread layout in the `.answer` element? But I'm really unsure of that.

Comment: @DavidThomas Hi! thank you for your interest, yes you are right it is what I was trying. There you have an outline of my idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I solve it:

```
let cardy01 = function () {
  card01.classList.add('animate');
  setTimeout(function () {
     card01.style.setProperty('transform', 'perspective(600px) translate(392px, 
     321px) rotateY(-180deg)', 'important');
  }, 2500);
};
let cardy02 = function () {
  card02.classList.add('animate');
  setTimeout(function () {
     card02.style.setProperty('transform', 'perspective(600px) translate(343px, 
     321px) rotateY(-180deg)', 'important');
  }, 2500)
 };
let cardy03 = function () {
  card03.classList.add('animate');
  setTimeout(function () {
     card03.style.setProperty('transform', 'perspective(600px) translate(292px, 
     321px) rotateY(-180deg)', 'important');
  }, 2500)
};
let cardy04 = function () {
  card04.classList.add('animate');
  setTimeout(function () {
     card04.style.setProperty('transform', 'perspective(600px) translate(242px, 
     321px) rotateY(-180deg)', 'important');
  }, 2500)
};
```

And repeat the same for each ending point, and for each `card`.